# Automatically moving range slider based on number of words in a text box - Perl script

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I am working in a market research field, so my programming code will be different than a regular development programming code.

Please click the link below to see the image.

https://ibb.co/6BxYPVv

My client wants a range slider below a text box and wants it to be moved automatically based on the number of words entering in the text box. The slide should reach the end level if a respondent entered at least 50 words. It seems to reward people for typing more.

I tried to convert the below syntax

```
<span class="Q1_wordcount"></span>
```

into below Perl script but it throws error in the 'return' statement

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="slider" id="myRange" value="
  [%
 
  Begin Unverified Perl
   
   
  return '<span class="' . Q1_wordcount . '"></span>';
   
  End Unverified
 
  %]
 ">
```

Please help me to correct this issue.

The complete set of my code is below.

```
<script>
// To count the number of words in a open end question
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateWordCount('Q1');
})
  
$(document).on('keyup', '#Q1', function(){
    updateWordCount('Q1');
})
  
function updateWordCount(Q1) {
    var matches = SSI_GetValue(Q1).match(/\S+/g);
    var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;
    $('.' + Q1 + '_wordcount').text(count);
     
}
 
</script>
 
<style>
/*Slider preparation
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}
 
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
 
.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
 
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
 
<div class="slidecontainer">
 <span class="Q1_wordcount"></span>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="slider" id="myRange" value="
  [%
 
  Begin Unverified Perl
   
   
  return '<span class="' . Q1_wordcount . '"></span>';
   
  End Unverified
 
  %]
 ">
 </div>
```

This is the error I get,

"Bareword 'Q1_wordcount' not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 17) line 1."

I tried to write the below HTML code

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="slider" id="myRange" value="0">
```

into below dynamic code (this is our market research method to include Perl script in a HTML tag)

```
 <input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="slider" id="myRange" value="
  [%
 
  Begin Unverified Perl
   
   
  return '<span class="' . Q1_wordcount . '"></span>';
   
  End Unverified
 
  %]
 ">
```

Please let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: What error do you get? You should also explain what "Begin Unverified Perl" means, it's far from standard.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my original question to add the details you asked. Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: What is `Q1_wordcount`? Is it a function call?

Comment: Q1_wordcount is a class. This class contains numbers of words entered in the text box.
`
var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;
$('.' + Q1 + '_wordcount').text(count);
`
`
<span class="Q1_wordcount"></span>
`

Comment: And Perl should somehow magically replace the class name with the content of the text box?

Comment: The variable 'count' (calculated using jQuery) will have a number (for e.g. 5) which is the total number of words entered in the text box. I would like to bring that variable in place of  value="0" below ```<input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="slider" id="myRange" value="0">``` using either jQuery or Perl. Target is dynamically range slider value to be changed once a new word is entered in the text box. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Does this kind of Perl have access to javascript variables? If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Bind "input" event to <textarea>
$('.text').on('input', wordCounter);

function wordCounter(event) {
  // Get the string value of .text
  const $count = $(this).val();
  /*
  Split that string value at every space into an array then return it's .length
  */
  const words = $count.split(' ').length;
  // Assign the word count value to <output> and <input>
  $('.display, .slider').val(words);
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI'
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: max-content;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

input,
textarea {
  font: inherit;
}

.text {
  width: 87.5vw;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  resize: vertical;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
}

.display {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90vw;
  min-height: 25px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="box">
  <textarea class='text' rows='5'></textarea>
  <output class='display'>0</output>
  <input class='slider' type='range' min="0" max="100" value="0" readonly>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```